# Python Selenium: How to wait for element in list using relative xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to scroll through a page and wait for a button inside each block to load before I scroll to the next block. This is how im trying to do this rn:

```
block = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'list')]")
    for x in block:
        coordinates = x.location
        driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0,{coordinates['y']})")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(x.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@class, 'button')]"))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(x.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@class, 'button')]"))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 78, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I thought maybe wait.until doesnt take lists, so I tried find_element instead and I got TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable

I can do this using abs xpath

```
r x in range(len(block)):
        coordinates = block[x].location
        driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0,{coordinates['y']})")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[{x+1}]/div/a")))
```

but I cant figure out a way to do it using relative xpath

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB I think I covered the problem with the first sentence in my post. I need to scroll through multiple elements, and wait on each element as Im scrolling until another element inside it is visible.